# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (cellForRowAtIndexPath) (Xib Custom Cell Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib, custom-cell

I get the error stated in the topic for unknown reason as the cell I reference(in DownloadProfilePicture) is visible. Basically, I am trying to replicate/adapt what is done in
[LazyTableViewImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.tableView.registerClass(topCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "topCell")
         self.tableView.registerClass(contentCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "contentCell")
         tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "topCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "topCell")
         tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "contentCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "contentCell")
         self.tableView.delegate = self
         self.tableView.dataSource = self
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let nodeCount = arrayOfPosts.count;
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
     tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("topCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! topCell
        if (nodeCount > 0)
        {
            if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
                // Set up the cell representing the app
                var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("topCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! topCell
                let post = arrayOfPosts[indexPath.row]
                cell.userName.text = post.userName
                cell.timeSincePosted.text = post.timeSincePosted
                // Only load cached images; defer new downloads until scrolling ends
                if (post.profileImage == nil)
                {
                    if (!tableView.dragging && !tableView.decelerating)
                    {
                        downloadProfileImage(post, indexPath: indexPath)
                        return cell
                    }
                    // if a download is deferred or in progress, return a placeholder image
                    cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: "titanic.jpg")
                                       }
                else
                {
                       cell.profileImage.image = post.profileImage
                }
                return cell
            }

func downloadProfileImage(post: Post, indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        println(self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows())
        println(indexPath)
        let cell:topCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! topCell
        cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: "img1")
    }
```

visiblePaths:

```
 (
    "<NSIndexPath: 0x7888f7b0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0x788a4d60> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}"
)
```

cell:

```
<NSIndexPath: 0x788a3c80> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
```

Comment: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("topCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! topCell`

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. Unfortunatly, it did not change anything.

Comment: FWIW The Cocoa* convention is that variables and method names start wit a lowercase letter, class names start with an upper case letter. This when I see: `topCell` I initially think that is is a variable. Conventions do help.

Comment: It would seem that there is no cell at the indexPath and you are explicitly unwrapping it. If the cell is not visible it will probably not exist. Never explicitly unwrap anything that could ever, under any circumstances be nil. From the docs: An object representing a cell of the table, or nil if the cell is **not visible** or **indexPath is out of range**. It is visible?

Comment: As you may see from the last part of my question ( the print out of values of visiblePaths and the cell I am referencing) , it is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the method the table view cell is created twice.
Try a structure like this, it must be guaranteed that a table view cell is returned

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let nodeCount = arrayOfPosts.count;
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("topCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! topCell
  if (nodeCount > 0)  {
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
      let post = arrayOfPosts[indexPath.row]
      cell.userName.text = post.userName
      cell.timeSincePosted.text = post.timeSincePosted
      // Only load cached images; defer new downloads until scrolling ends
      if (post.profileImage == nil)
      {
        if (!tableView.dragging && !tableView.decelerating)
        {
          downloadProfileImage(post, indexPath: indexPath)
          return cell
        }
        // if a download is deferred or in progress, return a placeholder image
        cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: "titanic.jpg")
      }
      else
      {
        cell.profileImage.image = post.profileImage
      }
    }
  }
  return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just did not include the full method, because it is a little bit long. You can check it out here http://pastebin.com/q7rLbLq9

Comment: make sure that the cell is instantiated only once in each branch. There are still two places. Remove the first (global) one. And avoid calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in other methods explicitly. Update the model and reload the table view

Comment: Alright! But then why apple calls cellForRowAtIndexPath in other methods?
from "LazyTableViewImages": http://pastebin.com/pV1C0Uvg